# Merging Refinement Step in the BIRCH clustering algorithm

Tags: clustering

I'm trying to understand the BIRCH algorithm, more specifically, the workings of a Clustering Feature tree. The paper describes 'A Merging Refinement' step when inserting a new entry into the CF tree, as follows.

[image]

If they are not the pair corresponding to the split, we try to merge them and the corresponding two child nodes. If there are more entries in the two child nodes than one page can hold, we split the merging result again.If I understand correctly, we pick the two closest entries that are not the seeds. We can merge the cluster features using the additivity theorem, for example, if the pair $i$, $j$ are to be merged to give the new merged feature $k$ we have $ CF_k = CF_i + CF_j$. However, I do not understand how to deal with the "two child nodes". I'm thinking that if they were just leaf nodes then we can try and merge them into one or two nodes depending whether or not all the CFs fit into one node (page size).

What happens when this is not the case, when the "two child nodes" have further children themselves?

[Here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/233269.233324) is a link to the paper I am referencing.

"If they are not the pair corresponding to the split, we try to merge them and the corresponding two child nodes. If there are more entries in the two child nodes than one page can hold, we split the merging result again."